# Points on a lemniscate

Tags: polar-coordinates

[image]

I have this lemniscate I plotted $r^2 = a^2 \cos 2\theta$ and that $a = 1$.

And I have these questions:

1) Are there values of $\theta$ that do not give any points on the curve? - My guess is a no since I know that the lemniscate rotates at $2\pi$.

2) Are there any values of θ that gives more than 2 points? - My guess is also no since every value $\theta$ gives a unique value.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1.  Yes, there are such values of $\theta$.  You can tell there are no points closer than $45$ degrees ($\pi/4$ radians) to the $y$-axis, and this corresponds to the fact that twice those angles have negative cosines, which cannot be the square of a real radius $r$.  2.  I'm not sure what this question is asking any more than Manuel Navarro García does in his answer, but if they're asking whether any values of $\theta$ yield more than two points on the lemniscate, then the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only plot the lemniscate in the range

$$\theta \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}\right]\cup \left[\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}\right]$$.

For other values of $\theta$, you have that $\cos(2\theta)<0$, so you cannot compute $r^2$ in polar coordinates.

So the first question is true.

I don't understand the second question.

Comment: Oops, I just saw a mistake in the question, it's actually asking if there is a value of θ that gives more than one point on the curve.

Comment: Correct the question, please. I agree with Brian Tung about the second answer.

Comment: Have corrected the question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!